# React-Native Components in ReactJS Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to use native react components (View, Text, TouchableOpacity etc.) in a ReactJS web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not using standard React or React Native. Here is a popular library which was designed to accomplish this: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web